# Dynamic routing with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I wonder how can I pass clicked item id to route path in React?

Here is my parent component

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Row>
          <ul>
              <li>....<li>
              ....
          <ul>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <ChildComponent rowData={this.state.data} />
        </Row>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a list element when I click to some of li element I get the `id` of this element. So far, everything is ok.

I wonder how and where I can pass the childComponent this item id like path parameter dynamically.

My id in `this.state.data.id`, and I want to create and pass this id to route of component

url will be like: `details/id`

So on click to li element route will go to child component and child component will have id of clicked item.

I'm using react-router

my route paths in my app.js:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" /> 
    <Route exact path="/callback" />
    <Route  path="/about" component={About} /> 
</Switch>
```

Comment: tried [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use url params. kindly check below url https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" /> 
    <Route exact path="/callback" />
    <Route  path="/about" component={About} /> 
    <Route  path="/details/:id" component={DynamicComp} />
</Switch>

var DynamicComp = ({match})=>({<div>{match.params.id}</div>})
```

Comment: I'll try but i'm confused. where i will link to my component? in my click function? where click working on list element click

Comment: On li click `<li onClick={e=>this.context.router.transitionTo('/details/'+id)}> Home</li>` or `<li> <Link to={'/details/'+id}>Home</Link></li>`

Comment: i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined when i try to add this in my click function :  onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                    this.context.router.transitionTo('/details/'+id)
                  }
i also don't understand where i will put it ? var DynamicComp = ({match})=>({<div>{match.params.id}</div>})

Comment: I can't. i need to be done it in onclick function only.

Comment: try `onClick={() => history.push('/details/'+id)}`

Comment: I resolved my problem with history push it's working now. but that time my dynamic component can't get props from parent           <ChildComponent rowData={this.state.data} /> this state wich i pass to my Child Component

Comment: inside child component `this.props.match.params.id` u will get url id value

Comment: yes with this way i get id but how i can get all state which i passed from parent to child with prop?

Comment: Thanks your advices is worked well :) i got the concept